# Temporizador + Semaforo JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funciones, setinterval

Estoy realizando un temporizador que sea un semáforo. Al momento de ingresar los valores, por ejemplo se ingresa 20 minutos, y debería estar el fondo verde. Cuando queden 5 minutos, debería cambiar a amarillo, y cuando quede en 0 min, en rojo.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head lang="es">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Temporizador</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1 id="demo"></h1>
  <form onkeypress="return validar(event)">
     <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="h" id="h" onkeyup="contar(this,s)"/>
     <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="m" id="m" onkeyup="contar(this,h)">
     <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="s" id="s" onkeyup="contar(this,m)">
    <input type="button" onclick="contador_regresivo()" value="ingresar" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
       var h = document.getElementById("h");
       var m = document.getElementById("m");
       var s = document.getElementById("s");

       var interval;
       //contador_regresivo() // 0 Dias 0 Horas 1 Minuto 20 Segundos

       function contador_regresivo() {
           h = parseInt(h.value);
           m = parseInt(m.value);
           s = parseInt(s.value);

           interval = setInterval(function() {
               setInter();
               innerHTML();
               // document.body.innerHTML = h+" h "+m+" m "+s+" s";
           }, 1000);
       }

       function setInter() {
           if (s > 0 && s <= 60) {
               s--;
           } else {
               if (m > 0 && m <= 60) {
                   m--;
                   s = 59;
               } else {
                   if (h > 0) {
                       h--;
                       m = 59;
                       s = 59;
                   } else {
                       setInterval("cambiar()", 1000);
                       clearInterval(interval);
                       //alert("Tiempo Finalizado");
                   }
               }
           }
       }
       
       function innerHTML() {
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" +            s;
       }

       function cambiar() {
           if (m == 9) {
               document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
           } else if (m == 5) {
               document.body.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
           } else if (h == 00 && m == 00 && s == 00) {
               document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
           }
       }
       //---------------VALIDAR---NUMEROS-------------------------------------------

       //Validar solo numeros input
       function validar(e) {
           tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
           if (tecla == 8) return true;
           patron = /\d/;
           te = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
           return patron.test(te);
       }
       
       //focus al ingresar un numero
       function contar(obj, destino) {
           if (obj.value.length == obj.maxLength) destino.focus();
       }
    </script>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. La función cambiar() debe ejecutarse en todas las condiciones (if, else if) y no con un setInterval como estaba. Como estaba en tu código lo que hacía era empezar a ejecutarse cuando el temporizador ya acababa.
2. No es necesario anidar tanto los if, de esta manera quedan más entendibles
3. En el else final de la función setInter(), se debe asignar 0 a h,m y s.
4. Dentro de la función cambiar() hay que hacer mas validaciones para que los colores cambien en el momento exacto (cuando comienza en temporizador, a los 5:00 y cuando acabe el temporizador)
5. Hay cosas que debes corregir si quieres que al volver a oprimir el boton ingresar siga funcionando el temporizador y no se dañe como pasa actualmente.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="es">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Temporizador</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
<form onkeypress="return validar(event)">
<input type="text" maxlength="2" name="h" id="h" onkeyup="contar(this,s)"/>
<input type="text" maxlength="2" name="m" id="m" onkeyup="contar(this,h)">
<input type="text" maxlength="2" name="s" id="s" onkeyup="contar(this,m)">
<input type="button" onclick="contador_regresivo()" value="ingresar" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var h=document.getElementById("h");
    var m=document.getElementById("m");
    var s= document.getElementById("s");

    var interval;
    //contador_regresivo() // 0 Dias 0 Horas 1 Minuto 20 Segundos

    function contador_regresivo()
    {

        h=parseInt(h.value);
        m=parseInt(m.value);
        s=parseInt(s.value);

        interval = setInterval(function(){setInter()
            
             innerHTML();
          // document.body.innerHTML = h+" h "+m+" m "+s+" s";
        },1000);
    }

    function setInter() {           

        if(s > 0 && s <= 60) { 
            s--;
            cambiar()
        }
        else if (m > 0 && m <= 60) {
            m--;
            s = 59;
            cambiar()
        }
        else if (h > 0) {
            h--;
            m = 59;
            s = 59;
            cambiar()
        }                            
        else {
            h = 0;
            m = 0;
            s = 0;                           
            clearInterval(interval);
            cambiar()
            //alert("Tiempo Finalizado");
        }                             
    }

    function innerHTML(){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = h+":"+m+":"+s;
    }

    function cambiar(){

      if(m>5 || (m==5 && s>0)){
         document.body.style.backgroundColor="green";
         
      }else if(m==5 && s==0){
         document.body.style.backgroundColor="yellow";
         
      }else if(h==00 && m ==00 && s==00){
         document.body.style.backgroundColor="red";             
      }
    }


    //---------------VALIDAR---NUMEROS-------------------------------------------

    //Validar solo numeros input
    function validar(e) {
        tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if (tecla==8) return true;
        patron = /\d/;
        te = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
        return patron.test(te);
    } 

    //focus al ingresar un numero
    function contar(obj,destino) {
      if (obj.value.length==obj.maxLength) destino.focus();
    }
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, ahora un poco de CSS y algunos botones y funciones mas y estaría ok, gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Amigo por favor marca el chulito de mi pregunta para que quede como la respuesta oficial gracias

Comment: Debes seleccionar esta respuesta como la correcta

Answer (score -1):

Con `window#setInterval` lo puedes hacer, pero si requiere algo más de sincronización y fluidéz, lo mejor será `window#requestAnimationFrame`.

#### window#setTimeout

```js
var minutes = window.prompt('Ingresa el tiempo en minutos');
var time = minutesToMilli(minutes);
var times = timesByColor(time);

highlight('green');
window.setTimeout(function() {
  highlight('ambar');
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    highlight('red');
  }, times.ambar);
}, times.green);


function minutesToMilli() {
  return minutes * 60000;  
}

function timesByColor(t) {
  var time = t;
  var g = time * .66;
  time -= g;
  var a = time / 3;
  time -= a;
  var r = time;
  
  return {
    green: g,
    ambar: a,
    red: r
  }
}

function highlight(color) {
  var actives = document.querySelectorAll('.spotlight.highlight');
  [].forEach.call(actives, function(active) {
    active.classList.remove('highlight');
  });
  var spotlight = document.querySelector(`.spotlight.${color}`);
  spotlight.classList.add('highlight');
}
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.semaphore {
  background-color: #333;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 140px;
}
.semaphore .spotlight {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), inset 0 0 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 70px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  opacity: .7;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .4s ease, box-shadow .4s ease, opacity .4s ease;
  transition: background-color .4s ease, box-shadow .4s ease, opacity .4s ease;
  width: 70px;
}
.semaphore .spotlight.green {
  background-color: #27ae60;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.semaphore .spotlight.green.highlight {
  background-color: #00c231;
}
.semaphore .spotlight.ambar {
  background-color: #f39c12;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.semaphore .spotlight.ambar.highlight {
  background-color: #ff9f06;
}
.semaphore .spotlight.red {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.semaphore .spotlight.red.highlight {
  background-color: #ff3824;
}
.semaphore .spotlight.highlight {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), inset 0 0 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="semaphore">
  <div class="spotlight green"></div>
  <div class="spotlight ambar"></div>
  <div class="spotlight red"></div>
</div>
```

#### window#requestAnimationFrame

Una opción mucho mejor y moderna es `window#requestAnimationFrame`. Es el reemplazo natural para `window#setTimeout` y `window#setInterval`.

Te pongo el mismo ejemplo del semáforo para `30s`: `20s` para el verde, `3.33` para el ámbar y el resto para el rojo (simulando el tiempo de un semáforo real).

```js
var time = Number(.5) * 60000; /* minutos a milisegundos */
var duration = durations(time);
var greenTurned = false;
var ambarTurned = false;
var redTurned = false;
var animationId;

(function() {
  var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame 
                      || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame 
                      || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame 
                      || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
  var cancelAnimationFrame = window.cancelAnimationFrame 
                      || window.mozCancelAnimationFrame;
  window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
  window.cancelAnimationFrame = cancelAnimationFrame;
})();

function semaphore(timestamp) {
  if(timestamp <= duration.green && !greenTurned) {
    turnLight('green');
  }
  if(timestamp <= duration.ambar 
     && timestamp > duration.green && !ambarTurned) {
    turnLight('ambar');
  }
  if(timestamp > duration.ambar && !redTurned) {
    turnLight('red');
  }
  if(timestamp >= time) {
    alert('Tiemeout!');
    return cancelAnimationFrame(animationId);
  }
  animationId = requestAnimationFrame(semaphore);
}

animationId = requestAnimationFrame(semaphore);

/**
 * Obtiene las duraciones de cada color.
 * Verde: 2/3 del tiempo total.
 * Ambar: 1/3 de (tiempo - verde)
 * Rojo: 1/3 de (tiempo - verde)
*/
function durations(t) {
  var g = t / 1.5;
  var a = g + (t - g) / 3;
  var r = a + 1; // is irrelevante
  
  return { green: g, ambar: a, red: r };
}

/**
 * Enciende un color y apaga los focos prendidos.
 * @param color El color a encender
 */
function turnLight(color) {
  // apaga los focos 
  var actives = document.querySelectorAll('.spotlight.turned');
  [].forEach.call(actives, function(active) {
    active.classList.remove('turned');
  });
  var spotlight = document.querySelector(`.spotlight.${color}`);
  spotlight.classList.add('turned');
  
  // resetea las variables de control
  greenTurned = false;
  ambarTurned = false;
  redTurned = false;
  
  switch(color) {
    case 'green': greenTurned = true; break;
    case 'ambar': ambarTurned = true; break;
    case 'red': redTurned = true; break;
  }
  console.info(`${color} encendido`);
}
```

```css
@import "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play";
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  color: #16a085;
  font-family: 'play';
  font-size: 42px;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.semaphore {
  background-color: #333;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 140px;
}
.semaphore .spotlight {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), inset 0 0 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  height: 70px;
  margin-left: 35px;
  opacity: .7;
  -webkit-transition: background-color .4s ease, box-shadow .4s ease, opacity .4s ease;
  transition: background-color .4s ease, box-shadow .4s ease, opacity .4s ease;
  width: 70px;
}
.semaphore .spotlight.green {
  background-color: #27ae60;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.semaphore .spotlight.green.turned {
  background-color: #00c231;
}
.semaphore .spotlight.ambar {
  background-color: #f39c12;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.semaphore .spotlight.ambar.turned {
  background-color: #ff9f06;
}
.semaphore .spotlight.red {
  background-color: #e74c3c;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.semaphore .spotlight.red.turned {
  background-color: #ff3824;
}
.semaphore .spotlight.turned {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), inset 0 0 20px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1>Semaphore</h1>
<div class="semaphore">
  <div class="spotlight green"></div>
  <div class="spotlight ambar"></div>
  <div class="spotlight red"></div>
</div>
```